# Terminal unaccessible after command

Tags: gnome-terminal

I did a clean Debian Jessie installation and was trying to set the fish as default shell, I've utilized the command `usermod -s /usr/bin/fish username` ([from here](https://askubuntu.com/a/26459/464568)), restarted the session and now I got an error:

> There was an error creating the child process for this terminal
>   Failed to execute child process "/usr/bin/fish" (Input/output error)

And the terminal is unaccessible. How can I undo that command?

Comment: You'll probably need to login as another user, or find a way to launch a terminal using a different command, e.g. `xterm -e /bin/bash` or such, and then run usermod to fix the shell for the account you broke. In the future, do this change only with some other terminal already open and running...

Comment: The alternate launch command worked. Thanks. About the "other terminal already open and running", it just took effect before I did the logout in the gnome session.